# How much does it cost the publisher to publish a book?

Tags: books, reference-request, publishers

I wonder how much it costs a publisher to publish a book (textbook or research book).

I'm looking for referenced numbers, not guesses. I am mostly interested in the fields of computer science and maths, and English-speaking venues, but I am curious about other fields and languages as well.

Comment: I am not an expert here, but I suspect that the only reasonably succinct general answer will be "It depends."  At one extreme there are **print on demand** publishing companies which are set up to print N copies of any text so long as you will buy N copies, and you would have to think that their cost is less than or equal to the price you pay for those N copies, thus for instance probably $100 or less in some cases.  At the other extreme publishers of a new edition of a best-selling textbook will pay whatever they think will net them more money, so surely more than $100K in some cases.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Sure, I'm ok with a distribution, or a dataset containing several samples.

Comment: So you want as an answer a statistical analysis of how much publishers spend on textbooks?  This seems too ambitious for someone to make on demand, but perhaps it already exists in the literature.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Ideally, yes, as I suspect like you that there is some variance.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood the question.  I was interpreting "a book" as a product being sold by the publisher.  Based on the answer, it seems that it means "each copy of a book."

Comment: @Pete L. Clark  One of my math books, paperback, 250 pages, B&W, 8.5 x 11, LaTeXed, is sold by Lulu for $9.54 plus shipping. I am not collecting royalties and Lulu had suggested a price around $20. All this to suggest that the prices currently charged by the few remaining, BIG, publishers have absolutely _nothing_ to do with their costs, even including marketing.

Comment: @schremmer: I'm not sure exactly why you made your remark.  I certainly agree with the sentiment behind it.  But you say that prices have "absolutely *nothing*" to do with costs.  I don't believe you: for big publishers, I am very confident that their prices are greater than or equal to their costs!

Comment: By the way, the above comment is mostly pedantic.  (Like many mathematicians, I am not only really good at being pedantic when I want to be, I have also been heavily conditioned to want to be.)  So I wanted to make sure to add: it's really great that you are making math texts available online which are literally free and also making them available for print at cost.  That's what everyone should be doing.  Congratulations.

Comment: This question is extremely vague as written. Is it asking how much it costs a publisher to bring a book to market, i.e., the costs of editing, design, illustrations, and so on? Is it asking the incremental cost of paper, printing, and binding (PPB) for one copy? Are we including the cost of setting up a print run, which by far the greatest cost involved in physical production by traditional printing? And all of these numbers vary enormously. PPB is approximately four times greater for a four-color book. A freshman physics textbook has perhaps 500 pieces of line art. A graduate math text...

Comment: ...might be ready to go to press as soon as they publisher gets a LaTeX file from the author. The economics of traditional printing are also completely different from the economics of print on demand (POD). And many publishers now use *both* traditional printing *and* POD for the same book.

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks for your comment. I'm interested in all types of costs. If that's too much for one question I can ask several ones. I don't have any preference.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't imagine how a well formed answer could look like. Do you think that there is a well formed answer to the question "How much does it cost a company to develop a car/smart phone/cupboard?"

Comment: @Dirk Yes, e.g. to manufacture a phone: http://spectrum.ieee.org/static/interactive-apples-and-samsungs-changing-smartphone-recipes

Comment: OK, manufacturing is something completely different from developing. For a publisher it is also completely different to print and ship a book or to develop a program and publish the book.

Comment: @Dirk Sure, Ben mentioned that earlier, see my reply.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: *I'm interested in all types of costs. If that's too much for one question I can ask several ones.* I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark There was no need to  "add" but I disagree: one just does what one thinks one ought/can afford to do. As for my comment, I did not intend to suggest that textbooks should cost around $10 but that, given the low cost of even color printing, I cannot see, as apparently you can, what could account for $200 books when they were LaTeXed by the author as is by now very often the case, if not the norm.

Comment: @schremmer: " I cannot see, as apparently you can, what could account for $200 books" Clearly my comments have not been understood: this is the exact opposite of the position I hold.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark You are entirely correct: I mentally interchanged costs and prices in your "I am very confident that their prices are greater than or equal to their costs!". I think, perhaps, because of the "equal". In any case, very sorry about that, if  only because I strongly dislike those who rebut something they haven't read correctly in the first place.

Comment: Would you please narrow it down to one of textbook or research book? The current version is too broad. Also, narrow it down to certain fields will help to reduce the scope of this question.

Comment: @scaaahu Sure, I'll do tomorrow.

Comment: @scaaahu ->  [How much does it cost the publisher to transform the draft of a textbook as given by the authors into a final publication (for web or print)?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65410/452)

Comment: @BenCrowell Why did you close the other question? I tried to follow your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2012/08/28/how-your-textbook-dollars-are-divvied-up) is one story on it from *US News & World Report*... Their example was a Calculus textbook selling for $289 at the bookstore.

> Where does all that money go? According to figures from the National Association of College Stores, an average of 21.6 cents of every dollar spent on a new textbook will go to the bookstore, whether for personnel costs, operations, or income. For Kadue's $289 textbook, that's around $62. Another cent of every dollar pays for the freight of shipping a heavy book around, so subtract another $3 from her cost. That leaves around $224 that goes to the publisher, or around 77.4 cents for every dollar.
>
> NACS no longer receives information from publishers about where textbook money goes, but as recently as 2008, they provided that cost breakdown. At that time, around 15.4 cents of every dollar went toward marketing the textbooks, 11.7 cents went to the authors, and the largest chunk—32.2 cents—went to the basics: paper, printing, and paying publishers' employees.

Comment: Many years ago I had a discussion with a shopkeeper of a technical bookstore in my country. They told me that only about 10% of the book's price, for imported books, would go to them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, although to be fair the question is too broad to be answerable. We could multiply the average cost of a book by some of the percentages quoted here, but the numbers listed here are not a full accounting, and in any case there is such a huge amount of variation from one book to another that the averages are basically meaningless.