# What is the difference between international, economy, and retail editions of textbooks?

Tags: books

I am looking to buy a used textbooks for my topology class. Some textbooks that I am finding online either have the labels international edition, economy edition, or no label at all (retail edition). My instructor did not specify which type, so I'm assuming he meant retail. Can I still buy one of the other two?

Comment: See the possible duplicate and also this one: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71211/20058